# How to use `projectile-multi-occur` to find a symbol at point?

Tags: projectile, interactive, thing-at-point

I am trying to make `projectile-multi-occur` to work with the symbol at point.

I have done that for `occur` already, this works:

```
(defun occur-symbol-at-point ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((sym (thing-at-point 'symbol)))
    (funcall 'occur sym)))
```

So now I tried to do the exact same thing with `projectile-multi-occur`, this does ***NOT*** work:

```
(defun projectile-multi-occur-symbol-at-point ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((sym (thing-at-point 'symbol)))
    (funcall 'projectile-multi-occur sym)))
```

Calling `projectile-multi-occur` with `M-x` works as I expect.

With the function above, I only get an `*Occur*` buffer, with only the search term, the same amount of times as there are hits.

What is wrong with my function definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the documentation for `projectile-multi-occur`:

```
projectile-multi-occur is an autoloaded, interactive and byte-compiled
function defined in projectile.el.

Signature
(projectile-multi-occur &optional NLINES)

Documentation
Do a multi-occur in the project's buffers.

With a prefix argument, show NLINES of context.
```

You’ll see that the only argument it accepts is the number of lines of context to show.

Edit: Since you asked how you might accomplish this even though `projectile-multi-occur` doesn’t take the argument you wanted to supply, I recommend reading the source of `projectile-multi-occur`:

```lisp
(defun projectile-multi-occur (&optional nlines)
  "Do a `multi-occur' in the project's buffers.
With a prefix argument, show NLINES of context."
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((project (projectile-acquire-root)))
    (multi-occur (projectile-project-buffers project)
                 (car (occur-read-primary-args))
                 nlines)))
```

This is very straight–forward. The second argument to `multi-occur` is the regexp to search for, so you could just call this yourself, supplying the thing at point instead:

```lisp
(defun projectile-multi-occur-symbol-at-point ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((sym (thing-at-point 'symbol))
        (project (projectile-acquire-root)))
    (multi-occur (projectile-project-buffers project)
                 sym
                 nlines)))
```

Just as a side note, you don’t need to use funcall in `occur-symbol-at-point` either. `(funcall 'occur sym)` is exactly equivalent to writing `(occur sym)`.

Comment: It also says "Do a multi-occur", and a multi-occur requires the string to be searched. I wrongly expected it to be replaceable as is, thanks. Then the follow-up question is: can I make the function call to `projectile-multi-occur` use the symbol at point as default input?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, this works. This is also simple enough to skip the `let` altogether. Now I just need to make it work when I replace `projectile-project-buffers project` with `projectile-current-project-files`, which somehow results in "Searched 0 buffers (11255 killed); no matches for xxxx".